# Git Bash でWindowsコマンドの結果が文字化けする

Tags: mingw, git-bash

Git Bash (MinGW) でWindows標準のコマンドを打つと結果が文字化けして表示されます。

`route /?` と打った例

[image: route /? と打った例]

ターミナルオプションで、ロケール設定をしてもうまくいきません。文字化けを解消できる方法はありますか。

[image: ターミナルオプション＞Text＞Locale(UTF8)]

Answer (score 1):

LANGにSJISを設定すれば日本語ファイル名も表示できました。

- `Options`で`Locale`と`Character set`を次のように設定します。

  - Locale : Ja_JP
  - Character set : SJIS
- ターミナル(mintty)で環境変数LANGを次のように設定します。

```
LANG=ja_JP.sjis
```

`route /?`を実行しても日本語が崩れません。

```
$ route /?

ネットワーク ルーティング テーブルを操作します。

ROUTE [-f] [-p] [-4|-6] command [destination]
      [MASK netmask]  [gateway] [METRIC metric]  [IF interface]

  -f           ルーティング テーブルにあるゲートウェイのエントリをすべてクリア
               します。このオプションをコマンドと併用した場合、コマンドを実行
               する前にテーブルがクリアされます。
```

漢字名のファイルも表示できました。

```
$ ls -l /c/junc/漢字名のファイル.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 XXXX XXXX 0 5月   9 01:59 /c/junc/漢字名のファイル.txt
```

※　XXXXは伏せています。

Answer (score 0):

## 手順

1. chcp と打ってから、Tabを押して、コマンド補完します
2. chcp.com と出るので、続けて、chcp.com 65001 とコマンドします
3. 確認に、再度、chcp.com と打つと、現在のコードページが確認できます

## 解説

実は、上記のロケールで、SJISを選択すれば、解消するのですが、それだと今度は、lsなどで、日本語ファイル名を表示できなくなります。これは、BashのロケールがUTF8であるためです。
なので、Windows標準コマンドに関しては、コードページをUnicodeにして、英語で表示させるのがベストプラクティスではないでしょうか。

もっと、いい方法があれば、どしどし、回答してください。